# Custom sampling points for anti-aliasing

Tags: c++, hlsl, antialiasing

I'm trying to write an anti-aliasing shader in HLSL, but I can't find any way to rasterize at a custom point. (in between pixels on the screen, but not orderly like supersampling)

Is there any way to do this completely in HLSL, or would it require external c++ code?

Currently I am creating a 2nd camera to rasterize my geometry on a screen of 1x1 at this point, and editing it from there, but it feels like this isn't the best way to do this.

Comment: If you do it as a post-process, you don't need to "rasterize a custom point".  You just sample the rendered scene at whatever coordinates you choose.

Comment: Lets say i have a hole in some geometry so i can see though it. Behind this hole there is a light, but none of the samples actually see though the hole, they get them around it. [http://i.imgur.com/UlJ4R8L.gif](http://i.imgur.com/UlJ4R8L.gif) in this image, the blue points are where it samples the texture, and the yellow area is the hole with the light. How would i re-sample just a single pixel where the hole is?

Comment: That's not antialiasing, that's drawing things that were never in the scene.  Also, you should edit that explanation into your question, so it's clearer what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I know the light has been passed though my vertex shaders unaltered, because when i move the camera I can occasionally see it, so it must be within the scene. I'm trying to implement a fix in the Pixel shader, specifically performing an additional render at that point to retain the quality of the image.

Comment: What I'm saying is that, once you're in the pixel shader, anti-aliasing is not going to get that light back out.  By definition, anti-aliasing only samples pixels which have been already been drawn (to a rendertarget other than the screen) and smooths their edges.  If you want light to appear when it wasn't in that pixel set, you need to do something else.  Perhaps you could draw the scene twice with a half-pixel offset, and sample both those renders for your final pixel output to screen.  But that is tantamount to supersampling.

Comment: Oh ok. I see what you mean. Do you know if there is a way to perform sampling in a non-uniform way but with a uniform camera? like say i perform a bunch of draws around the left area of the screen and not many on the right? Or if i cannot do this, how would I load the vertex data from the vertex shader again so I can manually rasterize it?

Comment: Sure, you could draw 1/4 of the screen at 4 times the resolution.  :)  Draw different parts, recombine them all at the end.  That's going to be a complex system covering several topics, so it'll be tough to get a complete answer here.